# How does google treat a href's description?

Tags: indexing, href

Let's say I have this link in my website:

```
<a href = "http://facebook.com">Big Cake</a>
```

Now, I gave it the description of "Big Cake",
but actually facebook.com has a different metadata description:

```
<meta name="description" content="Create an account or log into Facebook">
```

So, what will google use to describe that link's name in its search engine; Big Cake, or the meta name?

thank you!

Comment: What do you think? Does it seem likely that you can cause Google to rename facebook in its search results?

Comment: No, but I supposed there would be some kind of effect.

Answer (score 0):

Google will index that link as a link from your site to Facebook, ie from Facebook's perspective a 'backlink' to Facebook using the words 'Big Cake' as the link text. Google may or may not use the link text in its ranking algorithm but it's unlikely.

The description in the meta tag is used only in relation to the site itself. So if you Googled for 'facebook.com' Google may use the description content in its preview text.

Comment: But If I googled big cake, there would be absolute 0% effect for that link in the results? google will ignore it's descreption? what are the precentages...

Comment: That's the proprietary Google secret sauce - not public information.

Comment: As @Blorgbeard mentioned that's not common knowledge. There's a chance that if the website the link is present on were highly ranked, the text would influence what Google believes is the purpose of the linked url. Any influence would be slight and for something as big as Facebook would be zero.